# How to execute a command line command from VB.net

Tags: vb.net, windows

I have a program disable using Software Restriction Policies in Group Policy, I can bypass it using `runas`

the command is:

```
runas /trust:"Unrestricted" "c:/myprogram/test.exe"
```

I want to run that command using a program so that I don't have to type it at a command prompt.  How do I program it using VB.net? I tried this code but nothing happens; it just open a command prompt.

```
Dim proc As New Process()
proc.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe"
proc.StartInfo.Arguments = "runas /trustlevel:\""Unrestricted"" ""c:/myprogram/test.exe"""
proc.Start()
```

I also tried this, but it only opens a window and exits.  The program does not open.

```
Dim proc As New Process()
proc.StartInfo.FileName = "runas"
proc.StartInfo.Arguments = "/trustlevel:\""Unrestricted"" ""c:/myprogram/test.exe"""
proc.Start()
```

Comment: run the executable as administrator?

Comment: Try to add /K to the arguments of the first example "/K runas ....", the console will not close and you could see it there is an error

Comment: @Mahan, How do i do that on VB, I already disable my User Account Control Settings

Comment: @Steve, still the same, it only show the "RUNAS USAGE" on the DOS window

Comment: This probably won't work:  see the accepted answer at: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/cd82780b-6afa-4404-8515-5d646a5623de/runas-command-trustlevel-what-is-it-how-can-i-enable-additional-levels

Comment: @Derek, I have administrative privileges, when I tried it on .bat file..it works perfectly..but I need it on an .exe file

BTW, thanks on that link

Answer (score 0):

What if you write it out as a batch file (.bat) and then run it?